# Understanding type Parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I am trying to understand the type parameters in Scala. Let's look the following general example:

```
def func1[T](a : T) : T = a
```

I understand that func1 takes 1 parameter of any type, and returns that parameter of the very same type. What i don't understand is why:

```
def func1[T]
```

Why [T] right after function1?? We could simply write it without [T] after func1, like:

```
def func1(a : T) : T = a
```

1) What does that [T] means after func1 and why we put it there?

2) Why we do the same with classes?

```
class MyClass[T]{...}
```

I mean MyClass instantiations are of type MyClass. What does [T] means there?
You don't say i have a boolean Class of type MyClass, you say i have an object of type MyClass right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On your second point: you could be working with your class that's a container of other types of objects. Easy examples is List[String]. Seemingly your `MyClass` might be specialized... you might at times have `MyClass[String]` and some other `MyClass[Boolean]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. What does [T] mean after `func1`, and why do we put it there?

The `[T]` in `func[T]` defines a type parameter `T`. Your function can be called like `func[String]("Hello")`, in which `String` is replaced with `T`. You can also call it like `func("Hello")` because the Scala compiler is smart enough to infer that `T` must be `String`.

So why do we have to write `func[T]` when we define it? We need the distinction between arguments of a type given by a type parameter, and arguments given by an actual type. If you write it this: `def func1(a : T) : T = a`, then `T` has to be an actual type. For example:

```
class T

def func1(a : T) : T = a  // <-- This compiles now
```

2. Why do we do the same with classes?

You often want to contain an object of some type inside a class. If you define the type parameter at the class level, the type will remain the same throughout your class. Consider this example:

```
class Container[T](val t: T) {
    def isValueEqual(obj: T): Boolean = t.equals(obj)
}
```

Here, the `T` in `obj: T` is the same type as the `T` defined in `Container[T]`. Now consider this example:

```
class Container[T](val t: T) {
    def isValueEqual[T](obj: T): Boolean = t.equals(obj)
}
```

Notice that I defined a new type parameter at the method level as well (`isValueEqual[T]`). In this case, the `T` defined in the method will shadow the `T` defined on the class level. This means that they might not be the same type! You could call it like this:

```
val c = new Container("Hello")
println(c.isValueEqual(5)) // 5 is not of type String!
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis. 1) Yes i did a mistake. It was T instead of A. I corrected it now. 2) Although i am not sure i totaly understand the concept, i think i just got closer in understanding type parameters in Scala. 3) Because my reputation is less than 15, my vote feedback isn't recorded.

Comment: @Spartan It's over 15 now ;)