# Generic matrix in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, matrix, case-class

I am trying to create a generic matrix in Scala using a case class. I am writing here because I would greatly appreciate any feedback on my solution from anyone with insight.

```
case class Matrix[T](data: Vector[Vector[T]]){

  def foreachRowCol(f: (Int, Int, T) => Unit): Unit = 
    for (r <- 0 until data.size) {
      for (c <- 0 until data(r).size) {
        f(r, c, data(r)(c)) 
      }
    }

  def map[U](f: T => U): Matrix[U] = Matrix(data.map(_.map(f)))

  /** What follows are my implementations. */

  /** The element at row r and column c */
  def apply(r: Int, c: Int): T = data(r)(c)

  /** Gives Some[T](element) at row r and column c 
    * if r and c are within index bounds, else None
    */
  def get(r: Int, c: Int): Option[T] = 
    val opt: Option[T] = 
      if (r < data.size - 1 && c < data(r).size - 1){
        Some(data(r)(c)) else None
      }
    opt

  /** The row vector of row r */
  def row(r: Int): Vector[T] = data(r)

  /** The column vector of column c */
  def col(c: Int): Vector[T] = 
    for (i <- 0 until data.size - 1){
      data(i)(c)
    }

  /** A new Matrix with element at row r and col c updated */ 
  def updated(r: Int, c: Int, value: T): Matrix[T] = {
    val newData = {
      for (i <- 0 until data.size - 1){
        for (j <- 0 until data(i).size - 1){
          if (r == i && j == c){
            data(r)(c) = value
          }
        }
      }
    }
    Matrix[T](newData)
}

object Matrix {
  def fill[T](rowSize: Int, colSize: Int)(init: T): Matrix[T] = 
    new Matrix(Vector.fill(rowSize)(Vector.fill(colSize)(init)))
}
```

I have several questions:

1. I can't figure out the meaning of the first function foreachRowCol. What is the meaning of a function that has the function type (Int, Int, T) => Unit?
2. I think I've made an OK implementation. Is there any reason for me to feel that that is not the case?
3. My thinking on the updated method was something like this:
    a) iterate over the matrix
    b) replace the value at data(r)(c) with value
    c) yield a new Matrix with element at row r and col c replaced by value.
   Is my thinking correct or should I have implemented it differently?

Comment: Hi. Your 1st qu is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41899478/5986907). The others belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You think you "made an OK implementation" (#2), but you don't understand the meaning of it (#1)? Yeah, there is _definitely_ "a reason for you to feel that is not the case". Did you try to compile your code? Test it?

Comment: I am working on debugging right now.